# How are lottery winnings taxed when you move to a new state?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, lottery

If you win Mega Millions in a taxing state and choose the annuity option and later move to a non-tax state, will you still have to pay taxes to the state you won in?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag.

Comment: Not sure there's a question in this. As you say, you're taking the annuity and you move to a taxing state - start and end of story. If you want to see how it breaks down by state, see the mega page. https://www.usamega.com/mega-millions-jackpot.asp

Comment: If you win Mega-Millions, you don't care about the answer anymore.

Comment: @gef05 The OP says "_...and later move to a **non**-tax state_". In the UK, lottery wins aren't taxed at all, but if some states _do_ tax wins (and some don't), this seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @TripeHound Noted. But my comment remains the same - they are moving to a non-tax state... the OP answered their own question.

Answer (score 3):

Since US lottery winnings greater than $5k (I believe) have taxes automatically withheld from the payment, and the annuity payment always comes from the lottery organization in the state in which the ticket was bought, you have no way to escape owing (and paying) taxes to the state you bought the ticket in.

This is because:

- the state you live in charges you 0% tax.
- the state you used to live in no longer has a claim to your income (unless its the same as the state in the next point)
- the state paying you the annuity charges you X% in tax because they are the source of the payment and you aren't paying any tax in the state you live in.

None of this stops federal taxes of course!

This isn't your situation, but I think worth mentioning:   The only way you wouldn't owe X% state tax in the third bullet is if your current state imposed a tax rate higher than X% AND that state had tax reciprocity agreements with your current state.  In these cases, residence always takes priority over source.  That said, I believe Maryland and Arizona explicitly disallow reciprocity for out-of-state residents of their lottery winnings.  So you'd pay tax to both states in that case.